# My mobile hamburger menu overlaps below text item once I click on it. All other items cannot be seen or clicked because of this. How can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, responsive

The hamburger items overlap with my webpage contents (i.e.,_ here the text) I am not able to do anything as hamburger items code is written in easy way in JavaScript. What has gone wrong here?

Remaining everything i tried with has worked out, i am not able to do anything with js as i am a bit weak in it.

```js
const mainMenu = document.querySelector('.mainMenu');
const closeMenu = document.querySelector('.closeMenu');
const openMenu = document.querySelector('.openMenu');

openMenu.addEventListener('click',show);
closeMenu.addEventListener('click',close);

function show(){
    mainMenu.style.display = 'flex';
    mainMenu.style.top = '0';
}
function close(){
    mainMenu.style.top = '-100%';
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
body  {
    font-family: 'Arial' , sans-serif;
}
nav {
    background: #211e1e;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
nav .mainMenu {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
nav .mainMenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}
nav .mainMenu li a:hover {
    color: #007bff;
}
nav .openMenu {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 20px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav .mainMenu .closeMenu , .icons i {
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-facebook:hover {color: rgb(0, 110, 255);}
.fa-twitter:hover {color: rgb(86, 154, 243);}
.fa-instagram:hover {color: rgb(255, 0, 191);}
.fa-linkedin:hover {color: #007bb6;}

nav .logo {
    padding: 17px;
    margin: 6px;
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media(max-width: 800px){
    nav .mainMenu {
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: #000;
        transition: top 1s ease;
        display: none;
    }
    nav .mainMenu .closeMenu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 20px;

    }
    nav .openMenu {
        display: block;
    }
    nav .mainMenu li a:hover {
        background: none;
        color: rgb(255, 123, 0);
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }
    .icons i {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 12px;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="nav-bar">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <nav>
            <div class="logo"><h1>Perceived Ideas.</h1></div>
            <div class="openMenu"><i class="fa fa-bars">|||</i></div>
            <ul class="mainMenu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="quote.html">Quotes</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <div class="closeMenu"><i class="fa fa-times">X</i></div>
                <span class="icons">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                </span>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</section>
```

Output image

[image]

Comment: Add Higher z-index on `nav`

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: share your whole code. the hamburger menu looks good

Comment: @Deeksha added text as icons, as otherwise the icons aren't visbile without fontawesome

Comment: I am not getting you people. Could you please elaborate?